# The body that node Http-proxy gets is garbled

Tags: node.js

The body that node Http-proxy gets is garbled.

```
proxy.on("proxyRes",(proxyRes, req, res)=>{
    let headers = proxyRes.headers;
    let _end = res.end;
    let _writeHead = res.writeHead;
    if(proxyRes.headers &&
        proxyRes.headers[ 'content-type' ] &&
        proxyRes.headers[ 'content-type' ].match( 'text/html')) {
        let chunks;
        res.writeHead = function() {
            res.setHeader( 'transfer-encoding', '' );
            res.setHeader( 'cache-control', 'no-cache' );
            _writeHead.apply( this, arguments );
        }
        res.write = (data,encoding) => {
            if( chunks ) {
                chunks += data;
            } else {
                chunks = data;
            }
        }
        res.end = function(data,encoding) {
            if( chunks && chunks.toString ) {
                let body = chunks.toString();
                ....
                _end.apply( res, [ body] );
            } else {
                _end.apply( res, arguments );
            }
        }

    }
})
```

Body returned a lot of garbled code.
For example: �ｽT�ｽ[�ｽo�ｽﾌ移転�ｽ�ｽﾆ
But English has little effect.

Comment: Have you tried using the `header` `'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'`?

Comment: There is, but I am now trying to use the Chardet module Chardet.detect (Chunks:buffer]) to return an encoding string of ' Shift JIS '